# Prove semiring quality: If $A_k\in P$, all $k\in [1:n]$ then $\bigcup_{k}^n A_k = \bigcup_{k} \bigcup_{i=1}^N C_{ki}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $P$ be semiring of $X$ subsets.

**Prove:** If $\forall\ 1 \leq k \leq n, A_k\in P$, then $\bigcup_{k}^n A_k = \bigcup_{k} \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_{ki}$, here $C_{ki} \in P, C_{ki}$ -  disjoint and $C_{ki}\subset A_k$.

I think it comes from $A\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where $C_i$ disjoint and $C_i\in P$, but it is not clear how to make next step and why is double index is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the next step observe that:

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k$$ where $B_k=A_k\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i$.

The sets $B_k$ are disjoint and each of them can be written as finite union of disjoint elements of $P$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I can use my previous idea  (which could be proved using induction ), to show $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k = \bigcup_{k} \bigcup_{i=1}^{N_k} C_{ki}$, where all $C_{ki}$ are dijoint

Comment: Indeed you can. You are welcome.